# Getting error while applying df.apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When Product location is bangalore and chennai i want to divide bill quantity by 4 if not assign 0 for other locations

```
data['Newbillquantity']=data.apply(lambda x:x['Bill Quantity']/4 for 
x in data['Product location'] if ((x=='bangalore') & (x=='chennai')) else 0,axis=1)
```

Error is
data['Newbillquantity']=data.apply(lambda x:x['Bill Quantity']/4 for
x
in data['Product location'] if ((x=='bangalore') & (x=='chennai'))
else 0,axis=1)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be the for loop in your lambda function. You shouldn't need that. `apply` will loop over the rows in your dataframe for you. The `x` variable in your lambda will take on the value of each row. (The entire row. I typically use `row` as the variable name in apply lambdas for clarity.)

Try changing your code to

```
data['Newbillquantity'] = data.apply(lambda x: x['Bill Quantity']/4 if x['Product location'] == 'bangalore' or x['Product location'] == 'chennai' else 0, axis=1)
```

Note that I also changed `&` to `or`, because one variable (`x['Product location']`) cannot be two different values at the same time.